# Changing shutdown broadcast message

Tags: shutdown, defaults, broadcast

Is it possible to change the default message broadcasted by `shutdown` to something else?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [@Zelda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102714/7453) mentioned the messages are hardcoded. If you want to change it beyond amending the message with additional bits:

```
$ sudo shutdown -h +120 Save your work.
```

You'll need to recompile `shutdown`, creating your own executable that includes the customized message.

For example, [here's a sample source file, shutdown.c](http://fossies.org/dox/sysvinit-2.88/shutdown_8c_source.html). Lines such as these would need to be changed, and the .c files would need to be rebuilt.

```
/*
 *      Tell everyone the system is going down in 'mins' minutes.
 */
void warn(int mins)
{
        char buf[MESSAGELEN + sizeof(newstate)];
        int len;

        buf[0] = 0;
        strncat(buf, message, sizeof(buf) - 1);
        len = strlen(buf);

        if (mins == 0)
                snprintf(buf + len, sizeof(buf) - len,
                        "\rThe system is going down %s NOW!\r\n",
                        newstate);
        else
                snprintf(buf + len, sizeof(buf) - len,
                        "\rThe system is going DOWN %s in %d minute%s!\r\n",
                                newstate, mins, mins == 1 ? "" : "s");
        wall(buf, 0);
}
```

Comment: I'm kinda surprised that it's hardcoded. I wonder if they just didn't thought about it or if it was a conscious decision with security in mind, preventing someone to do a shutdown with pointless message or no message at all.

Comment: @talles - probably a little bit of both.  You don't want people playing games with the messages.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change the default message, you can only add some specific message of your by providing this after the time:

```
# shutdown 60 Down in an hour

Broadcast message from zelda@mongrel2_test
     (/dev/pts/0) at 6:37 ...

The system is going down for maintenance in 60 minutes!
Down in an hour
```

You do not have to quote the text after the number of minutes you provide shutdown. When cancelling a shutdown you can provide a message too.